# Conditionally execute code coming in from parameters

Tags: lua

I am trying to conditionally execute some chunk of code coming in through a function parameter depending on a global variable.

I tried the following:

```
function PrintCondition(CodeIfA, CodeIfB)
    if SomeGlobal == "A" then
        loadstring(CodeIfA);
        return true;
    elseif SomeGlobal == "B" then
        loadstring(CodeIfB);
        return true;
    else
        Error();
        return false;
    end
end
```

And then I call the function with

```
local temp = PrintCondition(
    [[
        print("global is A");
    ]],
    [[
        print("global is B");
    ]]
);
print(temp); -- prints 'true'
```

However, it does not seem to work. Even if I misformat the string to induce a syntax error I get nothing.

Am I trying something that cannot be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadstring` returns a function instance. You need to return the `loadstring` execution from your function:

```
function PrintCondition( CodeIfA, CodeIfB )
    if SomeGlobal == "A" then
        return loadstring(CodeIfA)
    elseif SomeGlobal == "B" then
        return loadstring(CodeIfB)
    else
        Error()
        return false
    end
end
```

and then for calling it outside:

```
local temp = PrintCondition(
    [[
        print("global is A");
    ]],
    [[
        print("global is B");
    ]]
)
temp()
```

Comment: Don't forget to make sure that you actually received a `function`: loadstring() will return nil + an error message if the passed string is not valid Lua code. While this might not be a problem with hard-coded code as in the example, it may be a big problem in other cases. The Lua manual uses the idiom `assert(loadstring(s))()` to load and run code from a string, so: `return assert(loadstring(codeIfA))` should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

All `loadstring()` (or `load()` in Lua 5.2) does is to load the string, it doesn't really run it, you need to save it to a function and then run it:

```
local func = loadstring(CodeIfA);
func();
```

Comment: This solution works as well, but I used @hjpotter92 's solution. Thanks anyway!